# Swift UserDefaults returns nil

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

Trying to learn doing a todolist; I have two viewcontrollers, one to store and one to display in a table view. my table returns nil; where am I going wrong ?

Storage view:

```
    var toDoStorage = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "toDo")
    var toDoList = [String] ()

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if (toDoStorage as? [String]) != nil {
        toDoList.append(itemLabel.text!)
    } else {
        toDoList = [itemLabel.text!]
    }
    UserDefaults.standard.set(toDoList, forKey: "todo")
    itemLabel.text = ""
}
```

Display view:

```
    var toDo = [UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "toDo")]

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return toDo.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "IDCell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: toDo[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this you store array of strings

```
var toDo = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "todo") ?? [String]()
```

Comment: That worked ! do I have to use stringArray because the data is already an array ?

Comment: no you can use Object but better to say array string

Comment: I tried replacing stringArray with object but I get errors after; the variable is not recognised as array so I can't use count and indexpath.row

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "todo") ?? [String]()

Comment: sorry you need to use         let myarray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "todo") ?? [String]()

Comment: ok thanks so can't use object and cast it as array after. we have to define it as array in the userdefaults function if that makes sense ? not sure why but I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure your keys match..
You gave a typo in your key.. "todo" != "toDo"

Comment: Thanks I did not see that

Comment: it was a part of the answer Im sure but if I only correct the typo I had a display error in my table
the solution above worked